# Video compress based on device resolution

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, compression

I want to compress video without FFMPEG, I tried https://github.com/lalongooo/VideoCompressor it's working fine but when I testing in all device the resolutions are different, like I captured video in Moto-E after compress it will be 2.30 MB and in S3 it will be 1.50 MB so it's too blur result of S3,  I stuck in it from many days! Any another way of compress video If yes then please guys help to solve it!!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Ffmpeg is the only good option, I have had hard time searching for another.

Comment: It's check the licence version May be it's not free!!!

Comment: I don't believe we have app uploaded on store using ffmpeg.

Comment: Are you sure you have used ffmpeg for video compressed?

Comment: It was for other purpose

Comment: Ohk!!!  https://github.com/lalongooo/VideoCompressor  this compressor working for me but not for all device resolution, You have an idea about it?

Comment: No I haven't used it, my current app has video compressing which i have done it using ffmpeg.

Comment: Welcome and If you want to use ffmpeg,here is the [command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39444431/3117966) I have used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124035/discussion-between-komal-and-nisarg).